# WiX: Does setting MultiInstance attribute to yes generate unique component IDs for each instance transform, even when static guids are used?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation, wix3.8

I have two msi packages that gets triggered by a bootstrapper and together install a product. I have multiple instance transforms defined for each msi, and I want to set the MultiInstance attribute to 'yes' for all the components in the harvested fragment such that a new component GUID will be generated per instance transform. (It seems that for now, there isn't a heat parameter that you can set to do this, and it has to be accomplished via an xslt transformation.)

I'd want to use -gg flag for Heat to auto-generate static GUIDs because the install directory is set during run-time as a parameter and is not necessarily a standard directory.

Basically, the output should look like:

```
<Fragment>
    <DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">
        <Component Id="cmp32EAD7F5A154CBFA668F294AEEE77B45" Guid="{6529235A-EE06-47EB-A56B-1D016B2396CF}" MultiInstance="yes" >
            <File Id="fil3F2F6C0F947339E1ED2CF4459569CC5A" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.BIN)\File1.txt" />
        </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>
```

... Etc.

I'm wondering, even if the GUID is hard-coded such that the linker does not generate it (like above, instead of Guid="*"), will the MultiInstance attribute being set to 'yes' generate unique guids for each instance transforms' components? I sot of became confused about this when I was test calling the MsiGetProductCode by passing in a component guid for a file, which was defined like below:

```
  <Component Id="ProductComponent" Guid="{1C149757-1E1D-424D-AF77-A156CB87F0BF}" MultiInstance="yes">
    <!-- TODO: Insert files, registry keys, and other resources here. -->
    <File Id="Picture1" Source="C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Desert.jpg" ProcessorArchitecture="x64" />
  </Component>
```

* This is a test file that gets installed for all instance transforms defined.

I had two instances from the msi installed (Instance1, Instance2) and the MsiGetProductCode function ran as a part of a custom action that executes during uninstall. On the first execution of MsiGetProductCode, I got the ProductCode of Instance1. On the second execution of MsiGetProductCode (after Instance1 was removed), I got the ProductCode of Instance2. It seemed like that static component id had been used for both instance transforms.

Is the unique component ID generated by the MultiInstance attribute being set to 'yes' not supposed to replace that visible component guid? I haven't had any issues certain files or registry values not being removed due to a component still being used. Basically, I want to confirm that unique guids are being generated per instance and that it's safe to use the MultiInstance attribute to guarantee that component ID collisions will not occur, even when static guids are in use. Could someone kindly elaborate how this works in the background?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty easy to confirm WiX behavior just by logging the install.  Consider the following code:

```
           <Component Id="test" Guid="{EAF11690-2396-4EBE-A74D-37FA1751BBC3}" MultiInstance="yes">
              <File Id="test" Source="C:\windows\notepad.exe" KeyPath="yes" />
            </Component>

 <InstanceTransforms Property="INSTANCEID">
      <Instance Id="I01" ProductCode="{7474D99A-B56C-4767-B437-52F56746274A}" ProductName="ProductName2-1" UpgradeCode="{7C2BE622-7543-4F22-A0ED-A9FD28C78C8A}"/>
     </InstanceTransforms>
```

Logging the base and secondary installation reveals that the GUID is unique / transformed.

Another thought would be to extract the instance transform from the MSI and apply it using ORCA to see the differences.

> MSI (s) (E4:A4) [10:36:37:021]: Executing op:
>   ComponentRegister(ComponentId={EAF11690-2396-4EBE-A74D-37FA1751BBC3},KeyPath=C:\Program
>   Files
>   (x86)\MyCompany\ProductName2\notepad.exe,State=3,,Disk=1,SharedDllRefCount=0,BinaryType=0)
>
> MSI (s) (E4:DC) [10:37:04:234]: Executing op:
>   ComponentRegister(ComponentId={BEC4E6A5-9CFB-5C77-A854-CC0179CFEDCE},KeyPath=C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\My
>   Company\ProductName2\notepad.exe,State=3,,Disk=1,SharedDllRefCount=0,BinaryType=0)

Comment: Ah yes, I can see in the install log for each instance transform that a new guid is generated for the component containing the file, and that during the uninstall, it refers to that particular guid to remove the file. Thanks a lot. In that case though, where does the static guid initially assigned to that component (in the .wxs file) used? I didn't see the static guid I assigned it anywhere in the log file, but I am able to return the ProductCodes of my instance transforms by referring to that initial static guid. The static guid is mapped to the component when I view the msi with ORCA.

Comment: It's created by the compiler and placed into the instance transform.  I don't know if they randomize it each time or if they hash the instance id and the component id.  I would have to look at the source.